# Binary File - Editing

Tags: c++, file-io, binary

Please help i am having trouble with this function.  The code compiles and everything however it doesnt change anything in the file.  I am so confused what i am supposed to do....  I am supposed to choose a record from the file to edit and then change it, my current code allows me to choose but when i edit the record nothing is stored?

```
void editRecord(Cookie &type)
{
    fstream dataFile;
    int num;
    int count = 0;

    dataFile.open("/Users/jordanmcpeek/Documents/2014_Summer/CSC_250/Unit_7/cookie.dat", ios::in | ios::out | ios::binary);

    dataFile.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&type), sizeof(type));

    // While not at the end of the file, display the records
    while (!dataFile.eof())
    {
        // Display the records.
        cout << endl;
        cout << count << ". Description: ";
        cout << type.description << endl;
        cout << "Quantity Sold: ";
        cout << type.quantity << endl;
        cout << "Price: $";
        cout << type.price << endl;
        dataFile.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&type), sizeof(type));
        count++;
    }

    cout << "Which record would you like to edit?: ";
    cin >> num;
    cout << endl;
    cin.ignore();


    dataFile.seekp(num * sizeof(type), ios::beg);

    cout << "Please enter the new description for the cookie: ";
    cin.getline(type.description, SIZE);

    cout << endl;

    do
    {
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Please enter the new amount sold: ";
        cin >> type.quantity;
        cin.ignore();

    }while(type.quantity < 0);

    cout << endl;

    do
    {
        cout << "Please enter the new price: $";
        cin >> type.price;
        cin.ignore();

    }while(type.price < 0);

    cout << endl;

    // Change the record
    dataFile.write(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&type), sizeof(type));
    dataFile.close();

}
```

Comment: Did you try to run this in a debugger? Make sure the file is indeed opened successfully? And that the write operation succeeded as well?

Comment: Do you know how to check if an `fstream` operation has failed?

Comment: i know the file opens correctly because i have other functions that work, this one i am having trouble on

Comment: If you did read to eof the file would be in an error state.  You need to clear the error before expecting any other operation like seek to succeed.  That's why checking for errors is important.

Comment: putting a dataFile.clear(); after the read solved my problems.  Thanks Retired Ninja